# Can someone explain what does 5th line mean . i.e ADD . $HOME_DIR mean in docker file?

Tags: docker

I have a problem with 5th line of my Dockerfile. I couldn't figure out what that means.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

LABEL author= APPLE

LABEL company= PINEAPPLE

ARG HOME_DIR='/schooldata'

ADD . $HOME_DIRECT              ##[ this line ]

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR $HOME_DIRECT

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: I guess it means that some args are passed to `docker build` operation. like `docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 --build-arg FTP_PROXY=http://40.50.60.5:4567 .` HTTP_PROXY is argument.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?  [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) is one of the basic Dockerfile directives that copies content into an image.

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
ADD . $HOME_DIRECT
```

- `ADD` performs a resource copy from a source to the current built image with the following specificity : if that is recognized as an archive (tar,zip...), it copies its content, otherwise it copies the contained files/directories such as.

The two next arguments are the source resource and the target resource of `ADD`.

- `.` means that the source is the build context. Build context is the last argument of the `docker build` command : often we specify `.` such as `docker build FooTag .` to represent the current directory where the `docker build` command is executed but that may be different.
- `$HOME_DIRECT` is the target directory of the copy inside the built image.

---

As a side note, `ADD` has a quite complex behavior (it also may accept URL as source, so it should be favored over `COPY` only for special cases (URL and copy archive's content).
In most of cases that is indeed better :

```
COPY . $HOME_DIRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

It will add the content of your working directory (where the build command has been executed) into you image in the location defined in environment variable HOME_DIRECT

More details: [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)